# how to covert string format such as Aug 17 to date in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table and one of the fields is a varchar2 data type, it stores some date in a string format such as Aug 17, Sep 18 etc. I want to sort this field according to real date not alphabet, how can I convert these value to date?

Comment: Aug 17 of what year? Or is that August 2017 - and in that case, what day of the month?

Comment: Aug 17 means Aug 2017, just need to sort it according to year and month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `TO_DATE` function write `'Mon YY'` format be the second parameter include the language to make sure the format and `order by` it.  (thank for @Wernfried Domscheit point out)

```
SELECT TO_DATE('Aug 17','Mon RR', 'nls_date_language = american')
FROM DUAL
```

Here is a sample

```
with cte as (
    SELECT 'Aug 17' dt
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Sep 18'
    FROM DUAL
)

select To_char(TO_DATE(dt,'Mon RR', 'nls_date_language = american'),'Mon YY')
from cte
order by TO_DATE(dt,'Mon RR', 'nls_date_language = american') desc
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eb2b8dd09573a12ccedaaf214d13733c)

Comment: `YY` will interpret `'17'` and `'18'` as the years `17 AD` and `18 AD`, respectively. I suggest they should use `RR` as the format in order to interpret them as `2017` and `2018`, which would then sort correctly with dates in earlier years like `97` and `99`.

Comment: You should include the language as well: `TO_DATE('Aug 17','Mon RR', 'nls_date_language = american')`